# extract (ordered) pixel values on circle given midpoint and radius using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image and want to pull out intensities of pixels that belong to a circle of radius r around a midpoint (Mx,My).
The critical part is building the list of coordinates (x,y) which define the perimeter of the circle for lookup. I adapted a version of the [midpoint circle algorithm from rosetta](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#Python) but the points on the circle aren't ordered. Is there a smart way to obtain a list of coordinates that I can use for lookup of the intensity values in an image? Ideally avoiding numpy as I have to implement it without it (but I can use openCV). Any hints that would speed up the value lookup from the image once I have the coordinates would also be appreciated.

This is my code for the unordered list:

```
def circle(x0, y0, radius):
    f = 1 - radius
    ddf_x = 1
    ddf_y = -2 * radius
    x = 0
    y = radius

    clist=[]

    while x < y:
        if f >= 0: 
            y -= 1
            ddf_y += 2
            f += ddf_y
        x += 1
        ddf_x += 2
        f += ddf_x    
        clist.append([x0 + x, y0 + y])
        clist.append([x0 - x, y0 + y])
        clist.append([x0 + x, y0 - y])
        clist.append([x0 - x, y0 - y])
        clist.append([x0 + y, y0 + x])
        clist.append([x0 - y, y0 + x])
        clist.append([x0 + y, y0 - x])
        clist.append([x0 - y, y0 - x])
    return clist

c=circle(10,10,5)    
for i in range(len(c)):
    plt.plot(c[i][0],c[i][1],'o',color=[i/50.0,1-i/50.0,1])
```

Comment: What format is your image in if you're not using numpy?

Comment: for technical reasons I eventually have to implement this in ironpython where I cannot import numpy but I can import opencv.

Comment: You also imply you need an order of some sort? Also the code you have here seems to get the points for a filled circle instead of just the perimeter?

Comment: Also this doesn't work in your case then, as it uses numpy by way of opencv, but you can use the `cv2.circle()` function to draw a white circle on a black background, then use `numpy.nonzero()` to get a list of the perimeter coordinates.

Comment: `numpy.nonzero()` would NOT help because the points would not be ordered. According to the documentation: "The values in a are always tested and returned in row-major, C-style order."

Comment: Okay, but what kind of order are you looking for? If it's drawing order, so to speak, then see Piglet's answer.

Comment: a useful ordering for me would be to begin at an arbitrary angle, say to the right of the circle center (x,y)=(x+r,0) and then go clockwise or counter clockwise around the circle.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are built-in functions for that in opencv as mentioned in the comments.

To get a simple ordered list of coordinates on a circle just use trigonometry.

x_perimeter = x_center + sin(angle) * radius

y_perimeter = y_center + cos(angle) * radius

Do that for reasonable angle increments and you get the desired number of points in whatever order you like.

It's for sure not the most efficient way but its simple and intuitive. All you need is a function that gives you subpixel intensities which most image processing libraries provide. Otherwise write one your own or round the coordinate values.

Comment: thanks. I was hoping for a generic solution that will give me exactly the points of a rasterized circle. For your solution, I will have to guess the correct angle increment in order to obtain exactly one coordinate pair per pixel. see this wikipedia article for further description: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: I am hoping to do this at several hundred frames per second on a live video stream, so performance does matter and I would like to avoid sin and cosin as much as possible

Comment: In defense of sin and cos, they can be very fast, and if you really need it you can use a lookup table.